# The generalization of the problem in the entrance exam of TokyoTech(2019)

Tags: combinatorics

In 2019, TokyoTech(Tokyo Institute of Technology) set the problem below and this is said to be the hardest problems ever on university entrance exams since 2000.

*Let n be a natural number and $H_1, H_2, \dots, H_n$ be planes on space different from each other. By the planes the space was partitioned into $T(H_1, H_2, \dots, H_n)$ regions.*
*For example, If $n = 3$ and $H_1: x=0, H_2 :y=0, H_3 : z=0 $, then $T(H_1, H_2, \dots, H_n) = 8$.*

The original problems asked 3 values: the largest value, the second largest value($n \geq 2$), and the third largest value($n \geq 3$) that $T(H_1, H_2, \dots, H_n)$ can take.

My question is: what is the $k$-th largest value($n \geq k$) that $T(H_1, H_2, \dots, H_n)$ can take? Can there be simple expressions using $n$ and $k$?

Comment: To which vector space do the $H_i$ belong? Are they in $\mathbb{R}^3$, or $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I meant $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: Well, if all $k$ planes are parallel, they split $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $k+1$ regions. This is the lowest possible value of $T$.